# How to return different file types using @ResponseEntity in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm working on a project using React and Spring Boot.

There is a navigation bar with a "View Document" tab, React Router is used to make the navigation bar. When clicking the tab, an API call will be triggered to get a pdf file from backend and the file will be displayed in a separate windows tab.

There is a table showing business histories with a "Document" link in each row. When the link is clicked, an API call will also be triggered to get a file from backend. The file type depends on the file a customer uploaded previously. For example, if the customer uploaded a jpg previously, then the jpg file will be displayed in a separate windows tab when the link is clicked. Supported file types include pdf, jpg, jpeg, png, tif and gif.

According to my development specification, the byte[] document must be encapsulated into an object and codes are shown below.

```
@Data
public class Document implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private byte[] document;
}
```

Codes in controller layer are shown below.

```
@RestController
public class CompanyController {
    @Autowired
    private CompanyService companyService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/getDocument", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Document> getDocument() {
    try {
            Document document = companyService.getDocument();
            return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.ALL).body(document);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
    }
    }
}
```

Codes in service layer are shown below. At the moment I just want to test whether a test file can be returned to frontend, so the repository layer is skipped.

```
@Service
public class CompanyService {
    public Document getDocument() {
        try {
        Path path = Path.of("path of testing pdf file");
        byte[] file = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            Document document = new Document();
            document.setDocument(file);
        return document;
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    }
}
```

Since there are several file types have to be returned, I set contentType(MediaType.ALL). When I clicked "View Proposal" tab, there is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Content-Type cannot contain wildcard type '*'.

When I test returning a pdf file and set contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION.PDF), following messages are shown in console.

DEBUG et.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Found 'Content-Type:application/pdf' in response
WARN  ervlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class com.xxx.Document] with preset Content-Type 'application/pdf']

DEBUG  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

The corresponding codes in React are also shown below.

```
const handleViewDocument = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get("/getDocument", {
            responseType: "blob"
        })
        if (response.status === 200) {
            const pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
            window.open(pdfUrl, "_blank");
            URL.revokeObjectURL(pdfUrl);
        } else {
            console.error("Error retrieving proposal:", response.status);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error retrieving proposal:", error);
    }
}
```

I've studied following references and still can't figure out a solution. What can I do so that different file types can be returned as byte[] in a Document object and displayed to the frontend?

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-image-media-data

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-no-converter-with-preset

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest#2-the-default-message-converters